# Node, Mongoose, Redux: GET request failure

Tags: node.js, mongoose, redux, axios, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make the following get request, which is intended to simply return documents from a collection. Once I get the data, it should flow through a reducer into the redux state object. But the get request fails.

```
var QuestionModel = require('./src/models/fv-questionModel')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/FVDB')

var app = express();

app.use(compression())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.get('/api/recent', (request, response) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  // Get documents and perform callback on recentQuestions data
  QuestionModel.find((error, recentQuestions) => {
    if (error) {
      response.send('unable to retrieve data')
    } else {
      response.json(recentQuestions)
    }
  })
})
```

this request was working until I changed the structure of the data in the collection. Here is my current mongoose schema:

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  options: [{ oid: Number, choice: { name: String, count: Number } }],
  qid: Number,
})

const QuestionModel = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema, 'questionBank')

module.exports = QuestionModel
```

The previous schema:

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  options: Array,
  qid: Number,
})
```

Here is the Redux action that makes the GET request:

```
export function recentQuestions() {
  let recentQs = axios.get('/api/recent')
  return {
    type: 'GET_RECENT',
    payload: recentQs,
  }
}
```

And the reducer to handle that data:

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'GET_RECENT':
    return action.payload.data
  }
  return state
}
```

But when the GET request is made, it returns a '404: Not Found' error. When I navigate my browser to localhost:8080/api/recent I get the message 'cannot GET /api/recent'. The express server itself is working.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this request is no longer working. I know there are other questions about failed GET requests but none seem to pertain to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the redux action also not incorrectly written. axios.get returns a promise, you should wait for the api response to return and then dispatch the action.

Comment: @VivekN I am using the redux-promise middleware in my redux store. The api calls as written worked prior to changing the structure of data in the mongoDB collection.